# 'inf' in awk not working the way '-inf' does

Tags: text-processing, awk

Given a single column file of numbers, call it `f`, the following Awk code will return the maximum value

```bash
cat f | awk    '   BEGIN {max = -inf}
                       {if ($1>max) max=$1} 
                   END { print max }
               '
```

The same approach to get the minimum doesn't produce anything

```bash
cat f | awk '
               BEGIN  {min = inf}
                  {if ($1<min) min=$1} 
               END {print min}
            '
```

But if instead of using `inf`, I start off with `min = [some large number]`, if the number is large enough, depending upon what's in the file, then the revised code works.

Why doesn't `inf` work, and is there some way to make the `min` case work like the `max` case, without having to know what's in the file?

Comment: Funny workaround: Find the max first, then use that as parameter for min.

Comment: Probably what's happening here is that `inf` is just an uninitialized variable; when you use `-inf` it is being cast to a number (and becomes `0` - probably not what you want, but may appear to "work" if your inputs are non-negative) whereas when you use plain `inf` it is an empty string and the comparison becomes lexical

Comment: spot on by @steeldriver, if you pass a file with only negative numbers for the first solution, you will get `0` as output, which is wrong because input has only negative numbers.. there is no special `inf` variable defined by awk as far as I know

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The *actual* task** is best solved by initializing your max/min values not by an imaginary "smallest" or "greatest" number (which may not be implemented in the framework you are using, in this case `awk`), but by initializing it using *actual* data. That way, it is always guaranteed to provide a meaningful result.

In your case, you can use the very first value you encounter (i.e. the entry in the first line) to initialize `max` and `min`, respectively, by adding a rule

```
NR==1{min=$1}
```

to your `awk` script. Then, if the first value is already the minimum, the subsequent test will not overwrite it, and in the end the correct result will be produced. The same holds for searches of the maximum value, so in combined searches, you can state

```
NR==1{max=min=$1}
```

**As for the reason why your approach with `inf` didn't work** with `awk` whereas `-inf` seemed to, @steeldriver has provided a good explanation in a comment to your question, which I will also summarize for the sake of completeness:

- In `awk`, variables are "dynamically typed", i.e. everything can be a string or a number depending on use (but `awk` will "remember" what it was last used as and keep that information along for use in the next operation).
- Whenever arithmetic operations involving a variable are found in the code, `awk` will try to interpret the content of that variable as a number and perform the operation, from where on the variable is typed as numerical if successful.
- The default value for any variable that has not yet been assigned anything is the empty string, which is interpreted as 0 in arithmetic operations.
- The *variable name(*)* `inf` has no special meaning in `awk`, hence when used just so, it is an empty variable that will evaluate to 0 in an arithmetic expression such as `-inf`. Therefore, the "maximum search" with the `max` variable initialized to `-inf` works if your data is all positive, because `-inf` is simply 0 (and as such, the smallest non-negative number).
- In the "minimum search" problem, however, initializing `min` to `inf` will initialize the variable to the empty string, as no arithmetic operation is present that would warrant an automatic conversion of that empty string to a number.
- Therefore, in the later comparisons

  ```c
  if ($1<min) min=$1
  ```

  the input, `$1`, is compared with a string value, which is why `awk` treats `$1` as a string, too, and performs a *lexicographical* comparison rather than a numerical one.
- However, lexicographically, *nothing* is "smaller" than the empty string, and so `min` *never* gets assigned a new value. Therefore, in the `END` section, the statement

  ```c
  print min
  ```

  prints the (still) empty string.

(*) see [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584442/377345) on how *a string with content `"inf"`* can actually have a meaning in `awk`.

Answer (score 13):

Your approach doesn’t work because `inf` doesn’t have a special meaning in GNU AWK in its default non-POSIX mode. As a result, it’s interpreted as a variable name, and since the variable hasn’t been set to anything, its value is 0 in an arithmetic context, and the empty string in a string context. Thus your code will only find the maximum value if it’s positive (since `max` is initialised in an arithmetic context), and won’t find the minimum value (since `min` is initialised in a string context); see [AdminBee’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584437/86440) for details.

To determine the minimal and/or maximal values in a file (or stream), you should follow the advice given in [AdminBee’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584437/86440).

However, if you’re using GNU AWK, you can calculate `log(0)` to initialise your variables with positive or negative infinity, and use that in a manner similar to your approach:

```c
BEGIN { max = log(0) }
$1 > max { max = $1 }
END { print max }
```

```c
BEGIN { min = -log(0) }
$1 < min { min = $1 }
END { print min}
```

The only advantage of this approach compared to initialising the values from the first line, is it provides distinctive results when no values are processed — positive or negative infinity end up being reliable indicators that no value was seen. (There are other ways to determine this, including checking for an empty string as opposed to 0 when initialising from the first line.)

With GNU AWK in POSIX mode (`POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`), or other POSIX-compliant AWK interpreters such as `mawk`, providing `"inf"` as a *string* in an arithmetic context produces infinity, thanks to [`strtod`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html):

```c
BEGIN { max = "-inf" + 0 }
$1 > max { max = $1 }
END { print max }
```

```c
BEGIN { min = "+inf" + 0 }
$1 < min { min = $1 }
END { print min}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107742/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-inf-in-awk-not-working-the-way-inf-doe).

Comment: In any awk (posix or not) a `"+inf"+0` will always become the positive `inf` that you want to use. An string `int` without a sign, doesn't, so, it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

There are, in fact, three values of infinity: `-inf` `+inf` and `inf`, and, to add more complexity to an issue that should be easy, in awk, there are quoted and unquoted code constants.

To show what I mean, try this (shell code in awk 4.2.1 (current Debian 10)):

```bsh
for cmd in original-awk "busybox awk" mawk nawk awk; do
    printf '%-6.5s' "$cmd"
    $cmd 'BEGIN {
        a="-inf";b="+inf";c="inf";
        d= -inf ;e= +inf; f= inf;
        printf "-∞%4s%4s +∞%4s%4s ∞%4s%4s | -∞%4s%4s +∞%4s%4s ∞%4s%4s\n",a,a+0,b,b+0,c,c+0,d,d+0,e,e+0,f,f+0}
    ' file
```

To get:

```
bawk  -∞-inf-inf +∞+inf inf ∞ inf inf | -∞   0   0 +∞       0 ∞       0
busyb -∞-inf-inf +∞+inf inf ∞ inf inf | -∞   0   0 +∞   0   0 ∞       0
mawk  -∞-inf-inf +∞+inf inf ∞ inf inf | -∞   0   0 +∞   0   0 ∞       0
nawk  -∞-inf-inf +∞+inf inf ∞ inf   0 | -∞   0   0 +∞   0   0 ∞       0
gawk  -∞-inf-inf +∞+inf inf ∞ inf   0 | -∞   0   0 +∞   0   0 ∞       0
```

The table presents quoted and unquoted assignment to variables (abcdef).
For each case, the value as read by awk and as converted to number (var+0).

That says that a `"-inf"` stays as so even when numeric, a `"+inf"` gets converted to a numeric `inf` (without sign) and that a quoted `"inf"` might become either `inf` or `0` depending on the implementation (its 0 in nawk and gawk).

When unquoted, both `-inf` and `+inf` become `0` (except in bawk where `+∞` is understood as the empty string "" and converts to `0`).

Oddly enough, when unquoted, all `inf` are interpreted as the empty string.

But all unquoted `-inf`, `+inf` and `inf` become 0 when used as `var+0`.

So, for what you meant to do, you need quoted `"-inf"` and `"+inf"`, never `inf`:

```bsh
cat file | awk  '  BEGIN { max = "-inf"+0; min = "+inf"+0 }
                         { if ($1>max) max=$1
                           if ($1<min) min=$1
                         } 
                   END   { print min, max }
                '
```

Maybe, a easier (not portable0 way to understand it is to execute:

```c
gawk 'BEGIN{
               a="-inf";b="+inf";c="inf";
               d= -inf ;e= +inf; f= inf;

               print a,   typeof(a),   b,   typeof(b),   c,   typeof(c)
               print a+0, typeof(a+0), b+0, typeof(b+0), c+0, typeof(c+0)

               print d,typeof(d),e,typeof(e),f,typeof(f)
               print d+0,typeof(d+0),e+0,typeof(e+0),f+0,typeof(f+0)
      }'
```

Which will print:

```
-inf string +inf string inf string
-inf number inf number 0 number
0 number 0 number  unassigned
0 number 0 number 0 number
```

Of course, the correct and portable solution is to give value to the `max` and `min` variables right from the start:

```bsh
cat file | awk  '  NR==1 { min = max = $1 }
                         { if ($1>max) max=$1
                           if ($1<min) min=$1
                         } 
                   END   { print min, max }
                '
```

### ---

The description [from the awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/POSIX-Floating-Point-Problems.html#DOCF102) is:

> - With the `--posix` command-line option, `gawk` becomes “hands off.” String values are passed directly to the system library’s strtod() function, and if it successfully returns a numeric value, that is what’s used. By definition, the results are not portable across different systems. They are also a little surprising:
>
> ```
> $ echo influence | gawk --posix '{ print $1 + 0 }'
>   -| inf
> $ echo 0xDeadBeef | gawk --posix '{ print $1 + 0 }'
>   -| 3735928559
> ```
>
> - Without `--posix`, `gawk` interprets the four string values ‘+inf’, ‘-inf’, ‘+nan’, and ‘-nan’ specially, producing the corresponding special numeric values. The leading sign acts a signal to gawk (and the user) that the value is really numeric. Hexadecimal floating point is not supported (unless you also use --non-decimal-data, which is not recommended). For example:
>
> ```
> $ echo nanny | gawk '{ print $1 + 0 }'
>   -| 0
> $ echo +nan | gawk '{ print $1 + 0 }'
>   -| +nan
> $ echo 0xDeadBeef | gawk '{ print $1 + 0 }'
>   -| 0
> ```
>
> `gawk` ignores case in the four special values. Thus, ‘+nan’ and ‘+NaN’ are the same.
>
> Besides handling input, `gawk` also needs to print “correct” values on output when a value is either NaN or infinity. Starting with version 4.2.2, for such values `gawk` prints one of the four strings just described: ‘+inf’, ‘-inf’, ‘+nan’, or ‘-nan’. Similarly, in POSIX mode, `gawk` prints the result of the system’s C `printf()` function using the `%g` format string for the value, whatever that may be.